# MySQL Stored Procedure that returns query result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it possible that a MySQL function/stored procedure returns a query result?

Because I want to have this on PHP:

```
SET @csum:=0; 

SELECT 
    datvalor AS 'Date', 
    company AS 'Company', 
    (@csum:=@csum + amount) AS 'Sum'
FROM tbl_test
ORDER BY datvalor
```

but PHP can´t run multiple lines, right?

I've searched but everyone says that a procedure can't return a table. How will you solve this?

I don't want to put the Sum calculation on php, the goal here is too generate everything on MySQL

Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research, I've found that the way is use mysqli (MySQL Improved) instead of mysql, just don't know the little details (yet)

Answer (score 0):

No, PHP can run multiple lines query. You just to concatenate strings.

e.g.

```
$sql = "";

$sql .= "SELECT ";
 $sql .= "   datvalor AS 'Date', ";
 $sql .= "   company AS 'Company', ";
 $sql .= "   (@csum:=@csum + amount) AS 'Sum'";
$sql .= " FROM tbl_test";
$sql .= " ORDER BY datvalor";
```

Comment: My bad, what I meant was that PHP can't run multiple querys in one mysql_query.